# jQuery bind function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seem to have problem with jQuery `bind()` and `unbind()` functions. They seem to not get executed at all. Here's the code I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    var init = function() {
        $.get('test.php', function(j) {
            if(j.r && j.r == 'error') {
                console.log("1");
                $('#far').bind('click', function() {
                    console.log("2"); return false;
                });
            } else {
                //getData();
            }
        })
    }();

    var getData = function() {
        $('#far').unbind('click', false);
    };

    $('#far').click(function() { ... });
});
```

Console only shows me `1` and no errors. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong since there are no errors and jQuery docs and StackOverflow has given me the same answer. I'm using jQuery 1.4.4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if(j.r && r == 'error')` should be `if(j.r && j.r == 'error')`

Comment: This was typo only here, sorry.

Comment: What is the expected behavior ? `console.log("2");` will be executed when you'll *click* on the `#far` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you're binding event before it's created, so use `live` instead.

Comment: You shouldn't use $.live() as its depreciated; use $.delegate() instead for jQuery < 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

By calling your `getData()` function at the end of the $.get() function you are unbinding the event as soon as you bind it. Try commenting out the `getData()` call in the `$.get()` function and see if that helps.

Comment: No, it did not help. Even if I unbind it as soon as I bind it, should `2` still appear in console?

Comment: Not true. There's a `return false;` there.

Comment: the console.log("2");  will ONLY execute on the click event, which does not occur prior to the unbind.

Comment: Thank you, when I click on the link (`#far`), I get `2` in console but link still work.
`2 minutes later.`
I also had to use `live()` function. Thank you everyone!